# How use "segment" in OneSignal with when POST to API?

Tags: php, push-notification, onesignal, segment

Im trying to POST a push to OneSignal service. I can make it work including "**include_player_ids**".. but can't make it work with "**segments**"

Im trying this:

```
$data= array("app_id" => "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "contents" => array("en" => "Check this!") ,
         "filters" => array("segment"=> "test"),
        "big_picture" => "http://www.xxxxx.com/img/logo2.png"
);
```

Response:

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic with a valid REST API key. ) [reference] => Array ( [0] => https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids ) )
```

Also trying this:

```
$data= array("app_id" => "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "contents" => array("en" => "Check this!") ,
        "segments" => "all",
        "big_picture" => "http://xxxxxx.com/img/logo2.png"
);
```

Response:

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => You must include which players, segments, or tags you wish to send this notification to. ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, you have to add segments like this:

```
'included_segments' => array('test')
```

And the head of the CURL to post must contain the **api rest key**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic API-REST-KEY'));
```

Comment: OneSignal has Example API code here as well: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-to-a-specific-segment-create-notification